# How to load dynamic data to react-native-chart-kit?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Actually i'm would load data dynamically to [react-native-chart-kit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-chart-kit) but i can't find any documentation on how could i do it.

I have an API that give the data for each month where there was some income and the response look's like the following

```
[{"IMPORTO":722.51},{"IMPORTO":911},{"IMPORTO":1188.53},{"IMPORTO":12},{"IMPORTO":390.65},{"IMPORTO":54.98}]
```

I have yet a method where i fetch that data but i can't get how can i use it as dataset of the chart.

Here is the code of my Home.JS where i build the chart and GetData is the fetch function for API DATA:

```
  import React from 'react';
import {Text,View,Dimensions} from 'react-native';
import {LineChart} from "react-native-chart-kit";

const data = {
  labels: ["Gen", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "Mag", "Giu", "Lug", "Ago", "Set", "Ott", "Nov", "Dic"],
  datasets: [
    {
      data: []
    }
  ]
}
const chartConfig = {
  backgroundColor: "#e26a00",
  backgroundGradientFrom: "#fb8c00",
  backgroundGradientTo: "#ffa726",
  decimalPlaces: 2, // optional, defaults to 2dp
  color: (opacity = 1) => `rgba(255, 255, 255, ${opacity})`,
  labelColor: (opacity = 1) => `rgba(255, 255, 255, ${opacity})`,
  style: {
    borderRadius: 16
  },
  propsForDots: {
    r: "6",
    strokeWidth: "2",
    stroke: "#ffa726"
  }
}

export default class Home extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoading: true,
      dataSource: []
    };

  }

  componentDidMount() {
  this.GetData();
  }

  GetData = () => {
    return fetch('http://192.168.100.158:3000/data')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
      this.setState({
        isLoading: false,
        dataSource: responseJson
      });
    })
    .catch((error) =>{
      console.error(error);
    });
  }

  render() {
    data.datasets[0].data = this.state.dataSource.map(value => value. IMPORTO);

    return (
      <View>
      <LineChart
      data={data}
      width={Dimensions.get("window").width} // from react-native
      height={220}
      yAxisLabel={"$"}
      chartConfig={chartConfig}
      bezier
      style={{
        marginVertical: 8,
        borderRadius: 16
      }}
      />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I've tryed to set data = { this.state.dataSource.IMPORTO } but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your render method, change the data to come from the state.

```
render() {

    data.datasets[0].data = this.state.dataSource.map(value => value.IMPORTO);

    return (
      <View>
          <LineChart
              data={data}
              width={Dimensions.get("window").width} // from react-native
              height={220}
              yAxisLabel={"$"}
              chartConfig={chartConfig}
              bezier
              style={{
                    marginVertical: 8,
                    borderRadius: 16
              }}
          />
      </View>
    );
}
```

Now, when the asynchronous call "GetData()" finishes, it will update the state, and the component will re-render with the new data.

You could also set the initial values in the state itself:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       isLoading: true,
       data: {
           labels: ["Gen", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "Mag", "Giu", "Lug", "Ago", "Set", "Ott", "Nov", "Dic"],
           datasets: [
               {
                   data: []
               }
           ]
       }
    }
}

GetData = () => {
    const self = this;

    return fetch('http://192.168.100.158:3000/data')
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {

            // clone the data from the state
            const dataClone = {...self.state.data}

            const values = responseJson.map(value => value.IMPORTO);

            dataClone.datasets[0].data = values;
    
            self.setState({
                isLoading: false,
                data: dataClone,
            });
    })
    .catch((error) =>{
      console.error(error);
    });
}

render() {

    // since we're now referencing this.state.data, its value 
    // will be updated directly when we update the state
    
    return (
      <View>
          <LineChart
              data={this.state.data}
              width={Dimensions.get("window").width} // from react-native
              height={220}
              yAxisLabel={"$"}
              chartConfig={chartConfig}
              bezier
              style={{
                  marginVertical: 8,
                  borderRadius: 16
              }}
          />
      </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: so after doing the changed i get data[0].toFixed is not a function in line 72 where i set data = {this.state.data}

Comment: @IgorMytyuk It looks like the values of "data" should be numbers, since toFixed() is a method used on numeric values. I looked at the example of LineChart [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-chart-kit) and that confirms it.

I've modified the original answer to extract the numeric values from the response. Give that a try.

Comment: @IgorMytyuk I saw your comment earlier today about the "RNSVGPath" error - did you manage to get it to work?

Comment: @M Polak yes actually the problem was that i was loading chart with null data and then loading it from the API call just by waiting GetData() call to be completed before render the chart solved the problem, thank you

Answer (score 1):

This would definitely work for creating dynamic chart using react-native-chart-kit:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  Alert,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  ActivityIndicator,
  Dimensions,
  
} from "react-native";


import {
 LineChart,
  BarChart,
  PieChart,
  ProgressChart,
  ContributionGraph,
  StackedBarChart
} from "react-native-chart-kit";


class Linedchart extends Component {
  state = {
datasource:[]
  };


 
LineChart_Dynamic=()=>{


if (this.state.datasource){
if(this.state.datasource.length){

return(
<View>
  <Text>Bezier Line Chart</Text>
  <LineChart
    data={{
      labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June"],
      datasets: [
        {
          data:  this.state.datasource.map(item=>{
            return(
              item.students 
//you need to add your data here from JSON, and remember the data you are requesting should be integer.
            )
          })
          
        }
      ]
    }}
    width={Dimensions.get("window").width} // from react-native
    height={220}
    yAxisLabel="students"
    yAxisSuffix="k"
    yAxisInterval={1} // optional, defaults to 1
    chartConfig={{
      backgroundColor: "#e26a00",
      backgroundGradientFrom: "#fb8c00",
      backgroundGradientTo: "#ffa726",
      decimalPlaces: 2, // optional, defaults to 2dp
      color: (opacity = 1) => `rgba(255, 255, 255, ${opacity})`,
      labelColor: (opacity = 1) => `rgba(255, 255, 255, ${opacity})`,
      style: {
        borderRadius: 16
      },
      propsForDots: {
        r: "6",
        strokeWidth: "2",
        stroke: "#ffa726"
      }
    }}
    bezier
    style={{
      marginVertical: 8,
      borderRadius: 16
    }}
  />
</View>
)

} else {


return(


<View style={{justifyContent:"center",alignItems:'center',flex:1}}>


<ActivityIndicator size="large"/>

</View>

)
  }



}else {


  return(
  
  
  <View style={{justifyContent:"center",alignItems:'center',flex:1}}>
  
  
 <Text>no data found</Text>
  
  
  </View>
  
  
  
  )}

  }



//fetch your own data from here:



 get_chart=()=>{

  
        
              fetch('http://192.168.18.7:8000/api/linechart', {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                  Accept: 'application/json',
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                
              })
                .then(response => response.json())
          
                .then(response => {
                 this.setState({datasource:response})
             
                })
                .catch(error => {
                
                });
            




}










  componentDidMount=()=>{
   
    this.get_chart()
    
  }


  render() {


return(
<View>

{this.LineChart_Dynamic()}

</View>

)


}

}



export default Linedchart;
```

if you are interested in explanation see this article:https://baidar-sabaoon.medium.com/how-to-make-dynamic-charts-in-react-native-using-react-native-chart-kit-48e9e5f41485

Comment: I get data.map is not a function:(

Comment: The data must be "array" if you want to use map function, check that you are loading array into it or not.